# What kind of implant abutment is it?

Tags: dentistry, implant

My dentist has discovered an implant of unusual shape, see two x-rays of the same area,
[image]
To the left there is a normally-looking implant, but the other one seems unusual, the abutment does not seem to fit the main screw. Have anyone seen this shape of abutment before? Is this a defect in installation, or is this a special kind of implant design?

Comment: @Narusan, where did you see personal inclination in my question? But anyway, I edited out a part that might be construed as personal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is an [Ankylos](http://www.dentsplyimplants.com/en/Implant%20systems/ANKYLOS%20New/Overview) brand implant system.

It also appears that the thin neck of the abutment, while having some advantages of reducing area where microbiology might get in (due to minimized implant-abutment junction), is having some structural mechanical weakness, see [this blog](https://www.osseonews.com/abutment-fractures-with-anklyos-implant-system/). An opinion is that this system should not be recommended for mandibular molar implants, due to large ratio of
of occlusion surface to the size of abutment base.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: If this has answered your question, please self-accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes agree to the above answer. Just to add on, this is called platform switching. From bone level to soft tissue level (the gingival/biotype looks thick, most probably due to past gum disease)

Comment: The words "platform switching" do not ring much of sense to me. What is your opinion on mechanical strength (lack of thereof) of this system? Do you think it is good to use in molar areas?

Comment: @Ben Lim Welcome to Health.SE!  We require statements to be backed up by evidence found in reliable sources. Please take the tour https://health.stackexchange.com/tour and take a look at the other help docs to improve this answer. Currently it looks like it is on its way to a good answer but in its current form it violates site-policy.

Comment: I have used implants as short as 5.5-6 mm long in the molar areas but that is after I have no better choice like bone grafting options. The few cases I have done have 100% success after 5 years (please note that this is only in my personal situation)

Comment: And platform switch designs are not limited to the Ankylos brand.